# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: point = unknown

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0

Recently, I developed a feature to save and fetch points(lat and lon) from DB. It is working fine on my local, but on production database it is giving error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = unknown
LINE 1: ...s"."name" = '九龍灣' AND "region_points"."lonlat" = 'POINT(1...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "region_points"  WHERE "region_points"."name" = '九龍灣' AND "region_points"."lonlat" = 'POINT(114.20910358428955 22.321574434895677)'
```

I digged into `psql` and found that there is difference in `type` for the columns.

On production:

```
production=> \d region_points
                                     Table "public.region_points"
   Column   |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('region_points_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 lonlat     | point                       | 
Indexes:
    "region_points_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_region_points_on_lonlat" gist (lonlat)
```

Whereas, `type` of `lonlat` on my local machine is: `geography(Point,4326)`

```
development=# \d region_points;
                                     Table "public.region_points"
   Column   |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          
------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('region_points_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 lonlat     | geography(Point,4326)       | 
Indexes:
    "region_points_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_region_points_on_lonlat" gist (lonlat)
```

My questions are:

1. Is type wrong on my local or on production DB?
2. How can I fix this?
3. What is the difference between `point` and `geography(Point,4326)`?

---

I checked `postgis_full_version` on local and production DB's. Here are the outputs:

*Production:*

```
POSTGIS="2.1.4 r12966" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" (core procs from "2.1.5 r13152" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.1.5 r13152" need upgrade)
```

*Development(local):*

```
POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER
```

Is the error because of different versions?

Answer (score 2):

a) You are using the build-in postgresql's geometry data type and not Postgis Point data type. I would follow the production specifications. There are some VERY good reasons to switch the production db to use postgis datatypes but in production enviroments that is not always fearsable.

b) you can cast from point to geometry/geography and vice versa

```
select ST_geometryFromText('POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)')::point
select point(10.1,1)::geometry
select point(10.1,1)::geometry::geography
```

c)
Point is geo**metry** type while geography Points is geo**graphy**

Point Geometry features represent a point in a nd space usually in 2D space (x,y). The units of x,y are governed from the srid. The distance between two points is calculated by the euclidian distance.

On the other hand geography Points are points that represent locations in a sphere and the distance between is calculated by [great circles functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

[image]

You can cast from geometry to geography if and only if the srid of the SRID of the geometry SRID is set to 4326 :

```
select ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)', 4326)::geography
```

the opposite:

```
select ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)')::geometry
```

note that an SRID if 4326 is implied

**Update** 
The Geometric operators between postgresql Point data types are a bit different. You can find a complete list [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-geometry.html).

The "=" operator checks between areas. Since your geometries are points they dont have an area. Instead what you want "~="

so the query in your comment would be :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "region_points"  WHERE "region_points"."name" = '九龍灣' AND "region_points"."lonlat" ~= POINT(114.20910358428955,22.321574434895677);
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer @nickves. I tried your suggestion of casting.
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "region_points"  WHERE "region_points"."name" = '九龍灣' AND "region_points"."lonlat" = POINT(114.20910358428955,22.321574434895677);` but it gives me error `ERROR:  operator does not exist: point = point`.

Comment: Sorry, but I didnt got your point (a). Could you please elaborate it more please?

Comment: if you are asking about the pros/cons of using postgis datatypes over the native  geometry datatypes that is another question that I cannot fully answer. The second part is pretty straight forward. If you change something in a production server you are going to break something somewhere else, and your service will be halted until you find it and fix it. Your boss wont like that at all

Comment: Actually I am confused as to what we have on production - PostGIS datatype or PostgreSQL datatype?

Comment: it seems that it is postgres' Point type. http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html